# Why is an enum containing a Box not copyable?

Tags: rust

Boxes and arrays are copyable, so why does this not compile?

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
enum Octree{
    Branch(Box<[Octree; 8]>),
    Filled,
    Empty,
}
```

Compile error:

```
main.rs:3:17: 3:21 error: the trait `Copy` may not be implemented for this type; variant `Branch` does not implement `Copy` [E0205]
```

**EDIT:** Ok, so I don't want `Octree` to be copyable after all. But how do I make it mutable? I want to be able to change children of a node.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rust, but the error message implies that Branch is not copyable, therefore neither is the enum.

Comment: Yes, the problem is with Branch. I actually have a theory now why it doesn't work: making a shallow copy of the root of a tree would cause aliasing. But I can't figure out how to fix this. Without Copy I can't fill an array with Empy for example.

Comment: @Joonazan: `[Octtree::Empty, Octtree::Empty, Octtree::Empty, Octtree::Empty, Octtree::Empty, Octtree::Empty, Octtree::Empty, Octtree::Empty]`. Problem solved. (And yes, I am absolutely serious about that. If you wish to use arrays, that’s how you’d do it.)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Not very convenient. In Go for example you'd create an array of the desired size and then fill it. Rust needs some kind of immutable array that can be filled once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy is only for types that are trivially copyable. Box is not Copy because merely copying the pointer would violate the single ownership principle.

You want to use Clone and its clone method here.